# Lenovo IdeaPad L340 doesn't recognize touchpad

Tags: touchpad

This laptop I purchased for my wife came in Jan 2021 brand new. Touchpad was working but my wife complained that she hit the touchpad while she is using the keyboard to write things. So, I disabled it shortly after getting it. For the life of me, I don't remember how I did it that time.

Fast forward 2 years and change, she wanted a laptop with a larger screen and I purchased a 17 inch laptop for her and she wants to give this old Lenovo to a dear friend of hers. I tried everything that I can think of but can not enable the damn touchpad. Her friend has issues with her hands. Hence can not hold a mouse without her hands trembling. So, touchpad became quite important to turn on before the laptop goes to the new owner.

So far I have tried hitting F6/Fn-F6 in different combinations to turn the touchpad on (or OFF) but no dice.

I can not see touchpad under win-10 settings or device manager neither. Presumed I removed the device drivers somehow.

I went to Lenovo Vantage app. Scanned hardware and installed all suggested updates. Reboot several times. Yet I do not see a touchpad anywhere on windows.

I created a multiboot USB with a windows 10 ISO and a Ubuntu ISO, using YUMI. First booted to Ubuntu. No dice with Touchpad but an external USB mouse works just fine when attached.

Reinstalled win-10 from ISO. Still no sign of touchpad under device manager.

The only thing I couldn't find (I don't even know if it is even an option though) enabling or disabling touchpad from the BIOS.

I am at the end of my patience. This simple thing shouldn't take 5 days to figure out.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or haven't tried yet? Is there BIOS setting for touchpad? If yes, where in the BIOS should I go? Oh by the way, entering BIOS setup is a big challenge on this laptop. It s very temperamental. 9 out of 10 times it disregards the F2 key being pressed during restart (or start from cold).

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

> Reinstalled win-10 from ISO. Still no sign of touchpad under device
> manager.

The Touch Pad has been damaged (per your discussion) and needs to be replaced.  The Touch Pad is physically part of the keyboard assembly, so the hit probably cracked something. The Touch Pad is not separate from the keyboard.

I have seen hardware issues on ThinkPads where the device has been disappeared.

Two possibilities:

(1) Get the Hardware Maintenance manual and you or a friend order a keypad (which contains the touchpad) and replace it.

(2) Take the machine to a local shop and let them replace the touchpad and test it.

Of course, you can leave it like it is and use an external mouse or external device.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the laptop was handled with gentle care by my wife. I have inquired about any heavy objects dropping on it or any water spillage etc. The answer is negative.
But assuming this is the case, how hard is it to replace the touchpad and do you have any idea about the cost ?

Comment: Since the touch pad does not show up in device manager, the device has a hardware error of some sort (however caused) and the only way to correct that is to replace the keyboard.

Comment: Then, it is an external touchpad or trackball that is. Mouse is out of question as I explained in my answer and I do nit want to pay north of $200 to replace kbd/touchpad assembly for something I will be giving away.

Comment: So then in my answer near then end, I had said you could leave it as is and use and external device. You need one or the other.